# How to mimic two consecutive tabs behaviour of a browser in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement like below.
I have two URL's to be run in two different tabs of browser.
First URL with state as "mystate". This redirects to a login page.

https://localhost:9031/as/authorization.oauth2?client_id=ac_client&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonceid=123-456-789&prompt=&state=mystate&RequestTypeId=Authorize&overrideUseDefaultUI=

Second URL with state as "yourstate". This also redirects to login page.

https://localhost:9031/as/authorization.oauth2?client_id=ac_client&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonceid=123-456-789&prompt=&state=yourstate&RequestTypeId=Authorize&overrideUseDefaultUI=

On the second URL tab, if I try to login, this still throws me the state as "mystate" instead of "yourstate". This is the bug that I need to fix.

Well, my question here is, how do I replicate this behaviour of the browser in my Jmeter? Or how do I replicate this bug in my Jmeter. Because I know just by adding two simultaneous HTTTPRequest's, this scenario will not be replicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reproduce the issue using the browser you should be able to do this using JMeter, just carefully inspect the requests and make sure that JMeter sends the same request as the browser does.

Pay attention to the [request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header), especially to [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) as if you just use [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers to hit the URLs it might be not sufficient in order to replicate real browser's behaviour. Headers can be controlled using [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

Also be aware that if your application is relying on i.e. [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) unfortunately JMeter won't support this scenario because it cannot execute JavaScript, in this case you will have to use real browser automation framework like [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/), there is JMeter/Selenium integration called [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/), it allows to kick off real browser(s) from JMeter tests and execute arbitrary code orchestrating the browser simulating real user activity

Comment: Thanks to you. I have used HTTPHeaderManager, HTTPCookieManage as well as HTTPCacheManager. Now I see Jmeter replicating the same scenario. Thanks a lot :)